# SQL Table Locking

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL Server locking question regarding an application we have in house. The application takes submissions of data and persists them into an SQL Server table. Each submission is also assigned a special catalog number (unrelated to the identity field in the table) which is a sequential alpha numeric number. These numbers are pulled from another table and are not generated at run time. So the steps are

1. Insert Data into Submission Table
2. Grab next Unassigned Catalog
   Number from Catalog Table
3. Assign the Catalog Number to the
   Submission in the Submission table

All these steps happen sequentially in the same stored procedure.

Its, rate but sometimes we manage to get two submission at the same second and they both get assigned the same Catalog Number which causes a localized version of the Apocalypse in our company for a small while.

What can we do to limit the over assignment of the catalog numbers?

Comment: Are all three steps in the stored procedure encapsulated in a transaction? What is the isolation level set on the transaction?

Comment: Is it also an apocalypse if you have gaps in the assigned Catalog Numbers? i.e. If T1 is assigned a catalogue number and then hits an error then rolls back is it an issue if that catalogue number just gets skipped?

Comment: Sorry got called away and couldnt monitor my own question. So, 1) no, they are not currently in a transaction, just executed one after the other in the same sproc. and 2) gaps arent ideal, but they are far from apocalyptic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When getting your next catalog number, use row locking to protect the time between you finding it and marking it as in use, e.g.:

```
set transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ
begin transaction
select top 1 @catalog_number = catalog_number
  from catalog_numbers with (updlock,rowlock)
  where assigned = 0
update catalog_numbers set assigned = 1 where catalog_number = :catalog_number
commit transaction
```

Comment: -1. Row locking has nothing to do with transactions, it won't protect the catalog number at all. There is nothing that keeps two sessions from selecting the same catalog number before one of them uses it.

Comment: @Guffa The `updlock` prevents this. `UPDATE .. TOP and OUTPUT` could do this without the need for any select though.

Comment: @Martin: The updlock locks the table until the end of the transaction. As there is no transaction spanning both queries they have their own transactions, so the transaction and the lock ends before the second query starts.

Comment: yes, they should be run inside a transaction. of course. all important updates should be run inside a transaction.

Comment: That's a little harsh. setting REPEATABLE READ just introduced a bottleneck in the application.

Comment: safe access to this kind of centralised resource is always going to be a bottleneck, which is why databases have special features for ID generation that are not transaction-scoped. maybe it would be better to have multiple app threads loading submissions, but just one assigning catalog numbers to new submissions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an identity field to produce the catalog numbers, that way you can safely create and get the number:

```
insert into Catalog () values ()
set @CatalogNumber = scope_identity()
```

The `scope_identity` function will return the id of the last record created in the same session, so separate sessions can create records at the same time and still end up with the correct id.

If you can't use an identity field to create the catalog numbers, you have to use a transaction to make sure that you can determine the next number and create it without another session accessing the table.

Comment: +1 This is the obvious sane way, if you have the luxury of rewriting it

Comment: Won't the session lock the current row only, allowing the creation of a new row?

Comment: @ispiro: If you use an identity field, it's no problem if a different session creates a record at the same time, as you can get the id that was created in the session. If you have to determine the id first and then do the insert, you need a transaction so that you can make other sessions wait until you have performed both steps.

Comment: Thanks. oops, I meant transaction. Sorry. I'm talking about the second option (not using identity) - will a transaction really help? I thought transactions don't lock the entire table - so both concurrent operations might read at the same time, and decide to use the same id. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm quite a beginner.

Comment: @ispiro: Sorry if I didn't clarify this enough. You have to pick a transaction level that gives exclusive access to the table, otherwise you would get the problem that you describe.

Comment: a) Thanks for your patience. b) From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) it seems that there is no such isolation level. Even `SERIALIZABLE` will allow both concurrent statements to read the last catalog-number, And insert a new row with catalog-number+1. Only an explicit lock such as `TABLOCKX` will work here. (Or am I wrong?)

Comment: @ispiro: Yes, you are right. I thought that the highest transaction level would do that, but you need `tablockx` to lock the table from reading.

Answer (score 0):

I like araqnid's response.  You could also use an insert trigger on the submission table to accomplish this.  The trigger would be in the scope of the insert, and you would effectively embed the logic to assign the catalog_number in the trigger.  Just wanted to put your options up here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easy solution. No race condition. No blocking from a restrictive transaction isolation level. Probably won't work in SQL dialects other than T-SQL, though.

I assume their is some outside force at work to keep your catalog number table populated with unassigned catalog numbers.

This technique should work for you: just do the same sort of "interlocked update" that retrieves a value, something like:

```
update top 1 CatalogNumber
set in_use            = 1 ,
    @newCatalogNumber = catalog_number
from CatalogNumber
where in_use = 0
```

Anyway, the following stored procedure just just ticks up a number on each execution and hands back the previous one. If you want fancier value, add a computed column that applies the transform of choice to the incrementing value to get the desired value.

```
drop table dbo.PrimaryKeyGenerator
go
create table dbo.PrimaryKeyGenerator
(
  id            varchar(100) not null ,
  current_value int          not null default(1) ,

  constraint PrimaryKeyGenerator_PK primary key clustered ( id ) ,

)
go
drop procedure dbo.GetNewPrimaryKey
go
create procedure dbo.GetNewPrimaryKey

  @name varchar(100)

as

  set nocount                 on
  set ansi_nulls              on
  set concat_null_yields_null on
  set xact_abort              on

  declare
    @uniqueValue int

  --
  -- put the supplied key in canonical form
  --
  set @name = ltrim(rtrim(lower(@name)))

  --
  -- if the name isn't already defined in the table, define it.
  --
  insert dbo.PrimaryKeyGenerator ( id )
  select id = @name
  where not exists ( select *
                     from dbo.PrimaryKeyGenerator pkg
                     where pkg.id = @name
                   )

  --
  -- now, an interlocked update to get the current value and increment the table
  --
  update PrimaryKeyGenerator
  set @uniqueValue  = current_value ,
      current_value = current_value + 1
  where id = @name

  --
  -- return the new unique value to the caller
  --
  return @uniqueValue
go
```

To use it:

declare @pk int
  exec @pk = dbo.GetNewPrimaryKey 'foobar'
  select @pk

Trivial to mod it to return a result set or return the value via an OUTPUT parameter.